# Getting value of an attribute within namespace

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

I am trying to process the following XML:

```
<rif:Rif xmlns:rif="rif" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" rif:numeroRif="XYZXYZXYZ">
    <rif:Nombre>Nombre</rif:Nombre>
    <rif:AgenteRetencionIVA>SI</rif:AgenteRetencionIVA>
    <rif:ContribuyenteIVA>SI</rif:ContribuyenteIVA>
    <rif:Tasa />
</rif:Rif>
```

An I am using the next code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(result);
var q = from item in doc.Descendants()
        let attributeType = item.Attribute("AgenteRetencionIVA").Value
        select item;
```

I have problems to get the attribute `rif:AgenteRetencionIVA`. How do I to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like tou need to specify custom namespace:

```
string xml = @"...";

XName nameRif = "rif";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var q = from item in doc.Descendants()
        let attributeType = item.Attribute(nameRif + "AgenteRetencionIVA")
        select item.Value;
var a = q.ToArray();
```

Comment: @user2112467: Declare XName out of LINQ query and use it with each element name.

Comment: @user2112467: You're doing something wrong. Works fine for me. See recent update.