# LINQ to XML: Finding an element with a specific attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, xml-namespaces

To simplify the problem statement, I am trying to search and see if a certain element is present in my file. My XML file is an AndroidManifest.xml file, used in Android apps. Specifically, I am searching for an element of type "uses-permission" with an element name of "android:name" and a value of "android.permission.INTERNET". Simple enough, right?

The query is,

```
IEnumerable<XElement> address =
    from el in _rootElement.Elements( "uses-permission" )
        where (string)el.Attribute( "android:name" ) == "android.permission.INTERNET"
        select el;
```

The issue is that namespaces as in "android:name" can't be used within the query. So how do I make this query? I saw some complaining and suggestions elsewhere but can't incorporate them into my specific query.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.app.myapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="App">

        <activity android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden" android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerProxyActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting value of an attribute within namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096621/getting-value-of-an-attribute-within-namespace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `XNamespace` to represent a namespace prefix, and use `XNamespace`+attribute's local name to point to an attribute in namespace :

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
IEnumerable<XElement> address =
            from el in doc.Root.Elements("uses-permission")
            where (string)el.Attribute(ns+"name") == "android.permission.INTERNET"
            select el;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `XName` objects when trying to find objects with specific namespaces when using the LINQ to XML methods.

Simply put, namespace declarations obfuscate the true `XName` of a `XElement` or `XAttribute` in the LINQ to XML data structure.

`XName` is simply a construct around `{<namespace>}<object name>`

So what you should be looking for in your `.Attribute()` method call is not `"android:name"` but `"{http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android}name"`